# Build method is not associating in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still newbie in Rails, but got confused with the initialization of a HABTM association. Reading its documentation, it says

> When initializing a new has_one or belongs_to association you must use the build_ prefix to build the association, rather than the association.build method that would be used for has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many associations.

So, basically, let's suppose we have two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Inside organization_controller, since I'm using Devise, my create method should have something like this:

```
@organization = current_user.organizations.build(organization_params)
@organization.save
```

However, it is not working. With byebug, I checked that for the current_user.organizations, the new organization was there, but, if I call @organization.users, there's an empty array. Looks like it's required to run current_user.save as well, is it correct? I was able to associate both models with this code:

```
@organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
@organization.users << current_user
@organization.save
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should highly consider using **has_many, :through** as that's the preferred way to do these kinds of relationships now in Rails.

having said that if you want to use has_and_belongs_to_many associations yes its get stored in join table on main object save.